G string becomes out of tune in F shape barre chords
So I have been playing an acoustic guitar for quite some time and after buying my first electric guitar I've noticed a strange thing. Everything seems to be in tune and regulated, except one thing. When I try to play some F shape barre chords, the G string becomes a bit out of tune. It sharpens, to be exact. It is actually noticeable, especially at the first three frets. Whenever I try to play the F chord, for example, the G string sounds like a slightly sharpened A. However, it doesn't affect other chords that also involve the G string. I can play the A shape barre chords across the fretboard without any problems, at least right now. Maybe I just unintentionally bend the string somehow? Any advice/suggestion appreciated!

I believe you mean an E shaped barre chord playing an F chord with the barre at the first fret.

Since you say you checked the intonation already I think the culprit is one of two things:

Your nut slot may not be cut low enough on the G string causing the first few fretted notes to be sharp because of the string bending as you push it down. This sharpness will diminish as you go higher up the neck since the string will not be bent as much as you go up the fingerboard.

What to do: Test the individual notes on the G string with a chromatic electronic tuner from open to maybe fret 5 and see if frets 1,2,3 are sharper than the open string and the notes on the higher frets. If they are your nut slot is too high on the G string.

If the individual notes on the G string play in tune then you are likely pulling down with your 2nd finger when you play your chord (which is actually an F chord with an E shape, not an F shape like you mentioned) and bending the string slightly.

What to do: look at your fretting hand in a mirror and see if you are pressing straight down or if you are pulling towards the ground with that finger. The G string should appear completely straight and not bent by your 2nd finger.

I've also thought of the nut slot! I checked the individual notes right now and I guess it is actually the nut slot that causes this problem. I will check again a few times throughout the day though to be sure. Thank you!
P.S: Yeah, sorry about the "F shape barre chord", mixed it up a little :)

There’s nothing wrong with checking it more than once but there’s no reason to think it will change. A guitar tech can file it down easily and quickly but if you’re a good DIY’er you can do it if you have the right tools. There is plenty of good information online to help you do it correctly., good luck!

Good idea about the nut slot, but why would that affect only E shaped, and not A shaped barre chords? +1

@Tim Why would you think it would only affect E shapes? It will improve the overall intonation of the guitar. The OP probably noticed the G string problem on E shaped chords because of the M3 interval between the D and G strings, which stands out like a sore thumb when out of tune.

I thought it would only affect E shapes, 'cos that's what OP said.

@Tim My guess is everything related to the G string fretted in the lower register was out of tune sharp but it was most noticeable to them on the barre E chord. The open E chord was probably just as bad if not worse.

First thing to do is check the intonation. That means each string must sound the same on its harmonic (12th fret) as it does when fretted on that same 12th fret. You may need to adjust the saddles on the bridge to accommodate this.
Then, when that's spot on, it may be that you're bending the 3rd string slightly on your barre chords - a not uncommon phenomenon, where your middle finger can do just that.

I've checked the intonation a few times already, maybe missed something. I will try again though. Thanks! Talking about the bend, it's a little strange because it doesn't happen on my acoustic guitar. Maybe it is just easier to bend small gauge strings and that's what I do not on purpose, just because I am used to pressing hard.

There should be no need to press that hard on any well set up guitar.

@parensgvozdemvyhe The unwound strings change pitch more when bent than wound strings do, so in addition to probably more unintentional bending on electric, the effects of unintentional bending are more dramatic on an electric third string (which is usually unwound).

@ToddWilcox oh, I didn't know that! Thanks, I will check how it affects my playing

@Tim it's just that I bought an acoustic guitar from like a second-hand shop and first four to five months I struggled to play barre chords. Only after around half a year I figured out that my nut slot was almost uncut! Now I'm getting used to pressing easier
